# Android camera- always uses front camera

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

I am creating a phonegap android application which records videos. I am testing it on Android 2.3.5 device. Problem is that it always opens front camera. But I  want it to use back camera. See my code.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
/*have also tried  recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);*/
int quality = CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW;
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(quality);
recorder.setProfile(profile);
```

When tested with a phone which has only one camera it uses back camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the code where you actually open the camera?

Try:

```
Camera camera; 

//if you want to open front facing camera use this line   
camera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

//if you want to use the back facing camera
camera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
```